# const Vs function to create component in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How do  I make this component using `function` instead of `const`?

```
const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
  return <div>My Component</div>;
}
```

I tried doing this

```
function MyComponent (): React.FC { 
  return <div>My Component</div>;
}
```

However, my editor is highlighting the return statement and giving this error:

Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.
Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' provides no match for the signature '(props: { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null'.ts

Comment: That function doesn't _return_ a functional component, it _is_ one.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I recommend picking up the differences between various ways of declaring functions in JS. i.e you can declare functions as `function declarations` or `function expressions`.

Example:

```
function myFunction(){
    return 'This is a function declaration.'; 
}

const fun1 = function() {
    return 'This is a function expression using a normal function.';
}

const fun = () => {
    return 'This is a function expression with an arrow function.';
}
```

Now, to answer your question, you cannot use React.FC in a function declaration since in a function declaration when you do the following:

```
function fun() : React.FC {
//do something
}
```

Typescript interprets it in a way that you're trying to specify the return type of the fun() function. Instead, what you want to be doing is:

```
function HomeComponent(): React.ReactNode {
  return <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
}
```

So that TS understands that this function will return some type of a ReactNode.

When you have props with a function declaration, you'll be doing this:

```
type Props = {
  message: string;
}

function HomeComponent({ message }): React.ReactNode {
  return <div>{message}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first one actually, you return a Function component as you see the below code assigned to a const value so you should use (React.fn) for it:

```
(a const value)  =    ()=>{}
```

but in the second one, you create a function that returns an Element so you should use (React.ReactElement) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your editor is highlighting it because you are not returning a React Function Component, but a ReactNode.

This should help:

```
function MyComponent(): React.ReactNode {
  return <div>My Component</div>;
}
```